# How to block an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a responsive website, so there are certain images that I want to be hidden on mobile browsers.

How can I block the HTTP requests for those hidden images from happening?

Also, how can I block the request for a background image(or any image) and show a different one instead?

Comment: simply don't include them in the DOM or css. If it's in the DOM, it will be loaded regardless of it being visible or you changing the src.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use @media rules to only load certain CSS rules for mobile, desktop or tablet etc.

Comment: @chrisbulmer this does not prevent loading the images. most browsers load all rules and images, but only execute the needed ones.

Comment: @KevinB It's not universally true that loading will happen if it's not visible - although this is often expected. Also, an agent could - very much within allowed bounds - cancel a GET if the "src" is changed.

Comment: @chrisbulmer - I believe media rules do not stop the browser from loading images or assets. This is a sticky point with responsive design, especially on mobile platforms and slow connections.

Comment: Correct...media rules don't block HTTP requests on hidden content. This is exactly why i'm asking the question. I want to take my existing responsive site and prevent HTTP requests on hidden images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to block the requests. However there are ways of insuring that different images are sent to mobile browsers.

Here are some alternate approaches to the problem of sending different images to mobile browsers:

- [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/)
- [the srcset attribute](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/)
- [HiSRC](https://github.com/teleject/hisrc#readme)
- [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)
- [Responsive Enhance](https://github.com/joshje/Responsive-Enhance)
- [SenchaIO](http://www.sencha.com/products/io)
- [rwdImages](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImages)
- [Responsive Images](https://github.com/filamentgroup/Responsive-Images)
- [Use media queries](http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/?utm_source=html5weekly&utm_medium=email)

Comment: Theoretically, it could be possible for you to configure (or if that's not possible, rewrite) the HTTP server to block requests coming from mobile browsers (via User-Agent)

Comment: @NullUserException True. But, that would not be blocking the request. The request was still made. It would just be sending an empty response to users of those browsers.

Comment: Thanks! I'll probabaly use one of the js approaches you linked me to. For hidden images, I guess I will just replace them with a tiny 1px image that won't use much bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of the approaches or a combination of both:

1) Use Javascript/JQuery to load all background images and assets after page loads as needed by the layout. Media queries will not stop the browser from loading all images/assets.

2) You can look into setting up a file stream on the server with say PHP, in which you can check the user agent and determine if it is a valid request then stream the file to the browser. This approach will also give you better control over external links and downloads.

Hope this helps. Good Luck.